# Smoother movement or diagonal movement - Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, keyevent

I'm trying to get my `<div>` moving either smoother or diagonally. When pressing two keys like `W` and `D`, it only goes one direction. I would like to make it move diagonally. Is there a possible way to make the movement less choppy. `divShootingGallery` is the parent `<div>` or the gameboard and the `divShooter` is a temporary box. I would like to only use JavaScript and not jQuery.

Here's my code:

```js
function keyClick(){
  var divShooter = document.getElementById("divShooter");
  var divGameBoard = document.getElementById("divShootingGallery");

  switch(event.keyCode)
    {
    case 65://a to move left
      if(divShooter.offsetLeft > 0){
        //checks to make sure the left side of the shooter is not off the left side
        divShooter.style.left = divShooter.offsetLeft - 10 + "px";
      }else{
        divShooter.style.left = "0px";
      }
    break;
    case 68://d to move right
      if(divShooter.offsetLeft + divShooter.clientWidth < divGameBoard.clientWidth){
        //checks to make sure the right side of the shooter is not off the right side
        divShooter.style.left = divShooter.offsetLeft + 10 + "px";
        }
      else{
        divShooter.style.left = (divGameBoard.clientWidth - divShooter.clientWidth) + "px";
      }
    break;
    case 87://w key up for right player
      divShooter.style.top = divShooter.offsetTop - 10 + "px";
      if(divShooter.offsetTop <= 0){
      divShooter.style.top = "0";
      }
    break;
    case 83://s key down for right player
    divShooter.style.top = divShooter.offsetTop + 10 + "px";
      if(divShooter.offsetTop + divShooter.clientHeight >= divGameBoard.clientHeight){
      divShooter.style.top = divGameBoard.clientHeight - divShooter.clientHeight + "px";
      }
    break;
  }
}
window.addEventListener('keydown',keyClick,true);
```

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  }
#divShootingGallery{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
  width:1000px;
  height:600px;
  background:bisque;
}
#divShooter{
  position:absolute;
  left:475px;
  bottom:0;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="divShootingGallery">
    <div id="divShooter"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

btw "event" is missing from your keyClick() function

```
function ketClick(event) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this thread, your problem is quite similar:
[Player movement in javascript with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51456906/4289700)

Basically you have to implement the keydown and keyup events and take note which keys are currently down. Then you should use that information in a simulation loop in order to move the object correctly. The simulation loop can be a timer like this:

```
function moveObject() {
    ... check which keys are down and move accordingly ...
}

setInterval(function() {
    moveObject();
}, 100);
```