# Player movement in javascript with socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io, html5-canvas

Im currently making a html5 multiplayer game with socket.io.
My problem is that i can only move my character in a straight line, while i also want to be able to move diagonal across my canvas. What i mean by this is if i press the 'a' and 'd' key, my character moves diagonally to the bottom right. With my current code my character only moves to the right or down.

//client, how i capture my keyboard input.

```
document.onkeydown = function(event){
    console.log(`Keycode: ${event.which}`);
    if(event.which == 68 || event.which == 39)   //d of pijl rechts
        sock.emit('keyPress', 'right');
    else if(event.which == 83 || event.which == 40)  //s of pijl naar beneden
        sock.emit('keyPress','down');
    else if(event.which == 65 || event.which == 37) //a of pijl naar  links
        sock.emit('keyPress','left');
    else if(event.which == 87 || event.which == 38) // w of pijl naar omhoog
        sock.emit('keyPress','up');
}
```

//server,

```
sock.on('keyPress', (keypress) => {
    var currentUser = this[sock.id];
    if (keypress == 'up') {
        currentUser.y = currentUser.y - currentUser.speed;
    }
    else if (keypress == 'down') {
        currentUser.y = currentUser.y + currentUser.speed; 
    }
    else if (keypress == 'left') {
        currentUser.x = currentUser.x - currentUser.speed;
    }
    else if (keypress == 'right') {
        currentUser.x = currentUser.x + currentUser.speed;
    }
});
setInterval(function(){
   io.emit('update-players', Users);
},1000/30);
```

//client, how all players are drawn onto to canvas

```
sock.on('update-players', updatePlayers);
var updatePlayers= (Users) => {
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,10000,10000);
   Users.forEach((user) => {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = 'Images/player.png';
      ctx.drawImage(img,user.x,user.y,user.width,user.height);
      ctx.font = "20px Courier New";
      ctx.fillText(`${user.name}`,user.x,(user.y - 10))
   } 
});
```

sorry for my crappy english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we press two keys on the keyboard and hold them down, only the last key pressed gets repeated events in the *keydown* listener. So, for example, if you press DOWN and RIGHT "at the same time", only one will be repeatedly reported to the listener and the other will be ignored.

A better approach is to have listeners for the *keydown* and *keydown* events, like this:

```
var keyStates = {
    up: false,
    down: false,
    left: false,
    right: false
}

function updateKeyStates(code, value) {
    if(code == 68 || code == 39)   //d of pijl rechts
        keyStates.right = value;
    else if(code == 83 || code == 40)  //s of pijl naar beneden
        keyStates.down = value;
    else if(code == 65 || code == 37) //a of pijl naar  links
        keyStates.left = value;
    else if(code == 87 || code == 38) // w of pijl naar omhoog
        keyStates.up = value;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    console.log(`Pressed: ${event.which}`); 
    updateKeyStates(event.which, true);
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    console.log(`Released: ${event.which}`);
    updateKeyStates(event.which, false);
});
```

So we basically have a boolean variable for each direction. You should send that information (keyStates) to the server and it should do the math based on which keys are down.